# macOS terminal -> ssh centOS with X Forward -> qemu Debian - keyboard/mouse are not behaving correctly

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, qemu, macintosh, xforwarding

My situation:

- I am using a `Macbook` with `High Sierra` and it's default terminal application + `XQuartz`
- I am connected to the remote server running `CentOS 7` that acts as a hypervisor
- I am trying to create a `Debian 9` guest with `QEMU`.

I type in the following commands:

```
user@macbook $ ssh -Y user@centosserver
user@centosserver $ qemu-img create debian_guest.img 50G
user@centosserver $ qemu-system-x86_64 -hda debian_guest.img -boot d -cdrom debian-9.3.0-amd64-netinst.iso -m 4096
```

When I launch `qemu-system-x86_64` command the `X11` window appears with the default `Debian` installation screen (install, memtest, etc.), but I am unable to navigate it. However, the window responds to several keys and allows me to click the menu bar. It ignores arrow-keys and most alpha-numeric.

Is there anything I should configure in `X Forward` or `QEMU`? Is it a bug? By the way, the same happened when I tried to connect from `Arch Linux` several months ago.
Unfortunately, I am unable to connect a monitor and keyboard to the hypervisor server itself and I have to manage this remotely.

Comment: Well, in the end I've created a `Debian VM` under `Parallels` and connected to the `CentOS` via `Debian`'s terminal (`Konsole`) and it worked. Still, I have no idea how to solve the original issue with `macOS`.